# Custom taxonomy page template name and how to use it?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template

How to specify the page template name for my custom taxonomy and where it should be placed whether in page-template directory or at theme root directory?

eg. i have custom taxonomy **location_category** and it has many items like Africa, Asia, America etc.... like and some contains sub-items like "Asia" have sub-items 'China', 'India' etc..

How to define page templates structure for it ?

eg. taxonomy-asia.php at theme root directory is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> where it should be placed whether in page-template directory or at theme root directory?

It should be placed at the root directory of the the active theme.

If you take a look at [template heirarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies), you can see that for taxonomy the flow is:

```
taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php --> taxonomy-$taxonomy.php --> taxonomy.php
```

So the correct name for term (Asia) is `taxonomy-location_category-asia.php` instead of `taxonomy-asia.php` and the same for other terms also.